# PHP json_encode() in while loop

Tags: php, arrays, sqlite, while-loop, json

I am trying to use `json_encode()` in a while loop while getting database results. Here is my code:

```
<?

$database = sqlite_open("thenew.db", 0999, $error);
if(!$database) die($error);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$results = sqlite_query($database, $query);
if(!$results) die("Canot execute query");

while($row = sqlite_fetch_array($results)) {
  $data = $row['uid'] . " " . $row['username'] . " " . $row['xPos'] . " " . $row['yPos'];
}
echo json_encode(array("response"=>$data));

sqlite_close($database);

?>
```

The output of this is

> {"response":"lastUserID lastUser lastXPos lastYPos"}

I want it to be...

> {"response":["1 Alex 10 12", "2 Fred 27 59", "3 Tom 47 19"]}

etc.

So I want the `json_encode()` function to put ALL users into the array rather than the last one. How would I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<?

$database = sqlite_open("thenew.db", 0999, $error);
if(!$database) die($error);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$results = sqlite_query($database, $query);
if(!$results) die("Canot execute query");

$data = array();

while($row = sqlite_fetch_array($results)) {
  $data[] = $row['uid'] . " " . $row['username'] . " " . $row['xPos'] . " " . $row['yPos'];
}
echo json_encode(array("response"=>$data));

sqlite_close($database);

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
while($row = sqlite_fetch_array($results)) {
  $data = $row['uid'] . " " . $row['username'] . " " . $row['xPos'] . " " . $row['yPos'];
}
```

to

```
$data = array();
while($row = sqlite_fetch_array($results)) {
  $data[] = $row['uid'] . " " . $row['username'] . " " . $row['xPos'] . " " . $row['yPos'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Push each user to an array:

```
$data = array();
while($row = sqlite_fetch_array($results)) {
  $data[] = $row['uid'] . " " . $row['username'] . " " . $row['xPos'] . " " . $row['yPos'];
}
echo json_encode(array("response"=>$data));
```